# php preg_match issue with "[image: Inline images 1]" regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I try to use preg_match to find the phrase: "[image: Inline images num]" in the text
Unfortunately I could not,

this is my try:

```
preg_match('/^[image(.*)]$/',$text);
```

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape your `[]` as follows:

```
preg_match('/^\[image(.*)\]$/',$text);
```

Also, as @h2ooooooo said, this will have better performance:

`^\[image[^\]]+\]$`

It works now. You can see it here --v

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iK0nE9

Comment: Seems like you need to add the `$matches` parameter for the `preg_match()` to capture them.

Comment: thanks but i run a test to this text: pic number 1
[image: TEST 1]
pic number 2
[image: TEST 2]
pic number 3
[image: TEST 3]
 and it doesnt work :(

Comment: @sshashank124 it seems like it work on regex101 thank you, but i tried to run it on my server and i go this message Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash, this is my code $num = preg_match("\[image[^\]]+\]", $mail); **sorry* i forget to use "/" but still i have a problem cause num = 1 but it need to be 3

Comment: @IlanFinkel, Your regex needs to be as `/regex-shown-in-my-link/` instead of just `regex-shown-in-my-link`

Comment: @sshashank124 yes my mistake but still i have a problem cause num need to equal 3 and it equal 1

Comment: What do you mean `3`, do you mean the `3` from `[image: TEST 3]`?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/tU1jL1 i mean that $num should be 3 cause there are 3 images in the text

Comment: @IlanFinkel, Consider using the `m` and `g` flags as shown in this [demo](http://regex101.com/r/kR8mI6). It gets all matching results

Comment: @sshashank124 still have a problem i wrote this: $num = preg_match("/\[image[^\]]+\]/mg", $mail); and got this error Message: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: @IlanFinkel, Oh right. You don't have `g` for php, do `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match` but keep the `m` modifier in place.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match('/\[image:.*?\]/i', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}


Match the character “[” literally «\[»
Match the characters “image:” literally «image:»
Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “]” literally «\]»
```